# How to save the json listview content in Sdcard in text File Format?

Tags: android, file, listview, fileoutputstream

I have a `ListView` which consists of `json` data. I want to store the content using file. So I want to save the `ListView` in text file format into my SDCard. Is there any examples? Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: i want to store the listview content in my sd card folder in text file format

Answer (score 1):

Yes ofcourse, while displaying data into ListView, i am sure you are having JSONArray.

And you can easily convert the JSONArray or JSONObject into a string.

For example:

```
String strArray = myJsonArray.toString();
String strObj = myJsonObject.toString();
```

Now as you are having string values, you can write it into the files or store into the database.

Comment: yes.i am getting this string values.but how to write this two string values in a text file

Comment: @Rajesh see dear, there are many threads available on SO already for *writing into file*, can't you do R&D for the same?